Azure Automation Runbook won't connect to Managed SQL Instance
I've followed the instructions for implementing this "Update-SQLIndexRunbook" runbook. Instructions are essentially this:  https://microsoftlearning.github.io/dp-300-database-administrator/Instructions/Labs/13-deploy-automation-runbook-rebuild-indexes.html
Whenever I schedule the runbook or run it manually, it can't connect to the managed SQL Instance:

Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.)"

The automation account was created inside the same resource group and same geographic region. I copied & pasted the instance hostname from the SQL management screen (e.g., server.stuff.databases.windows.net) -- the same hostname I can connect to in SSMS when I'm connected to the Azure VPN.
Any insights here would be appreciated.

The error message indicates that the runbook is unable to establish a connection to the SQL Server. This can occur if there are network connectivity issues between the runbook and the SQL instance.
If you are able to access the SQL database when connected to the VPN, there may be an issue with the network. The SQL database might not be allowing connections from the automation account.
To resolve the issue, create a private endpoint for the automation account within the same VNet and subnet connected to the SQL database, and disable public access for the automation account.
I created SQL database with VNet configuration as below.
SQL Server configuration

Disabled public access and enabled a private endpoint in the same VNet and subnet that are connected to the SQL server for a secure connection in automation account as below.

Automation Runbook network configuration

Note: Make sure to create a runbook with PowerShell version 5.1 and install the SqlServer module


Install the SqlServer module by following the screenshot or import it from this URL.


I'm able to access the SQL database from automation runbook successfully.
Automation Runbook output

Reference: Troubleshoot connectivity issues and other errors with Azure SQL Database and Azure SQL Managed Instance
